Taxes are not being applied on line items when created from rest api
I am posting following data on rest api url "https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders"
{
    "payment_method": "cod",
    "payment_method_title": "Cash on delivery",
    "set_paid": true,
    "customer_id": 1200584, 
    "customer_note": "Some of my notes", 
    "billing": {
        "first_name": "Example", 
        "last_name": "Developer", 
        "address_1": "Example address", 
        "address_2": "Delhi2", 
        "city": "Delhi", 
        "state": "Delhi", 
        "postcode": "110020", 
        "country": "IN", 
        "email": "developer@example.com", 
        "phone": "9876543210"
    }, 
    "shipping": {
        "first_name": "Example", 
        "last_name": "Developer", 
        "address_1": "Example address", 
        "address_2": "Delhi2", 
        "city": "Delhi", 
        "state": "Delhi", 
        "postcode": "110020", 
        "country": "IN", 
        "email": "developer@example.com", 
        "phone": "9876543210"
    }, 
    "line_items": [
        {
            "product_id": "849660",
            "quantity": 1,
            "taxes": [
                {
                    "rate_code": "IN-DL-CGST-1",
                    "rate_id": "9193",
                    "label": "CGST",
                    "compound": false,
                    "tax_total": "0",
                    "rate_percent": "0%"
                },
                {
                    "rate_code": "IN-DL-SGST-2",
                    "rate_id": "9229",
                    "label": "SGST",
                    "compound": false,
                    "tax_total": "0",
                    "rate_percent": "0%"
                },
                {
                    "rate_code": "IN-DL-IGST-3",
                    "rate_id": "9265",
                    "label": "IGST",
                    "compound": false,
                    "tax_total": "38.095238",
                    "rate_percent": "5%"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "shipping_lines": [
        {
            "method_id": "flat_rate",
            "method_title": "Flat Rate",
            "total": "60.00"
        }
    ],
    "fee_lines": [
        {
            "name": "COD Charges",
            "total": "30.00"
        }
    ]
}

But the order is being created without taxes.
Is there any specifi key that needs to be posted on the api?
or is there any setting action filter etc
The order should be created with cgst, stgs and igst included in line data.

Try removing total from shipping_lines and fee_lines. That will let WooCommerce handle the calculations based on individual components (line items, fees) rather than global totals.

Oh, My issues was something else.

Glad you figured it out. Perhaps you could write a comment or post an answer to your problem, letting others know what/how you fix your issue. You can mark your own answer as accepted.
